# how to add pagination on dashboard filter by status in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add pagination on a filtered manager_level_two_dashboard. manager_level_two_dashboard is filtered by decision if true it shows on the dashboard if false it won't appear in the dashboard. but when I add pagination to project_manager_two_controller it won't render the page properly. I want 10 list entry on project_manager_two_dashboard but it shows less list entry if decision status is set to false.

project_manager_two_controller

```
   def index
     @project_sites = ProjectSite.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
   end
```

project_manager_two_dashboard.html.erb

```
  <% project_site.manager_remarks.each do |manager_remark| %>
    <% if manager_remark.decision == true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use includes for your requirement :-

```
def index
   @project_sites = ProjectSite.includes(:manager_remarks).where("manager_remarks.decision =?", true).order("project_sites.created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

For more reference... [#includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)